# JSF 2.0 and IE9 login

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, internet-explorer-9, weblogic

I built a web application using jsf 2.0 and primefaces. I'm using the j_security_chek to access a security area. It works fine in any browser, except in IE9. I set the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

I tried to find something similar to my problem and I got this:
[JSF web application not working in IE9. But it works fine in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348274/jsf-web-application-not-working-in-ie9-but-it-works-fine-in-ie8).

So, I'm not sure if using the filter it could help me. It doesn't make sense. And another forum also said that I could remove the meta tag from header. I've tried some of the possibilities but no success. 
Is there someone with knowledge of a solution to my problem?

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post" id="form_login">
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username"/>
    <p:inputText id="j_username"/>
    <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password"/>
    <p:password id="j_password"/>
    <h:commandButton  value="Login"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <a id="modalDialogButton" value="Modal" onclick="dlgInsertLogin.show();">Forgot password</a>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably need you to post the code and/or what happens when it doesn't work. Do you see errors? Could be as simple as something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531075/j-security-check-for-jsf-app-not-working-in-ie

Comment: At the first, thanks for the comment. I updated the post!